# npm install @nestjs/config fails with npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing

Tags: nestjs-config

I tried installing npm as described by the documentation using  `npm install @nestjs/config`
and the installation process failed.

I got an error message:

```
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '....0","lodash.get":"4.4'
```

and in the linked log file that the error message pointed to I found these lines as relevant:

```
 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@nestjs%2fconfig 16ms (from cache)
 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @nestjs/config@latest Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '....0","lodash.get":"4.4'
```

I tried installing on a new nestjs project and got same error results.

Answer (score 0):

I searched the web for this behavior but couldn't find anything for this specific error.

I then decided to try a specific release of @nestjs/config.

I went to the release page of nestjs/config: [Link...](https://github.com/nestjs/config/releases) and picked release 2.0.0.

Then I used the cli command to install that specific release :

`npm install @nestjs/config@2.0.0`   and it worked.

So there must be some problem with the default release at this moment and until the nestjs team fix it the solution will be to install a specific release.